# Checking the arity of a function

Tags: clojure, arity

When programming in haskell the `:type` command is of a great help.
We can quickly understand the purpose of some construct by knowing the arity and signature of a function.
For example:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Reader> :type (lift .)
(lift .) :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t) => (a -> m a1) -> a -> t m a1
```

Is there an equivalent in clojure for knowing the arity of a function (type is not relevant in clojure) ?

For example it was not easy for me at first glance to understand the bellow composition until I realize that (-) and (*) have a variadic arity:

```
(comp - *)
```

Comment: NB. the function returned by `comp` calls all the functions passed to `comp` except the last one with one argument and it calls the last one with as many arguments as are passed to it. Thus the variadic overload of `*` is relevant to understanding `(comp - *)`, but the variadic overload of `-` is not. See `(source comp)` for the actual implementation.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk Yep thanks for the precision, I had realize it using repl. But why `source`, `doc` and `find-doc` always return nil with lighttable

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/clojure/core.typed yet?

Comment: The only type system that I am willing to accept are the one that have the same feature of haskell one (no need for type annotation). :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use the REPL. Particularly, `(doc), (source), (find-doc)` utilities.

For example:

> > user=> (doc map)
> >     clojure.core/map
> >     ([f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls])
> >       Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to the
> >       set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set
> >       of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is
> >       exhausted.
> >       Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function f should accept number-of-colls arguments.

As you can see, it is easy to locate the arity.

I do agree though that Haskell is second to none in this area.

Answer (score 1):

The argument list(s) for a function are stored in the function metadata which you can get using `meta`:

```
(:arglists (meta #'*))
```

Comment: RuntimeException Unmatched delimiter: )  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)

Comment: @Chiron - Sorry, fixed

Comment: `:arglists` meta is not trustworthy, though – people can and do override the default, mostly for documentation purposes. This even happens in `clojure.core`, for example the macro expander for `defn` is a variadic function of 3+ arguments (of which the first two are the implicit macro arguments `&form` and `&env), but the `:arglists` attached wouldn't even be interpreted as variadic if actually used in a function/macro definition.

Comment: It look like it work for binded object but not for object like `fn`. `(meta (partial + 5))` -> nil

Comment: @MichałMarczyk there is the explanation :)